# complex join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Hy everyone,

I really need your help. I have to obtain the list (distinct) of all users who :
 - have a live checkin ( checkins.ctype = 'live' ) in a match
 - where they favorite team ( see fanusers_teams )
 - won by 3 ore more goals difference.

The favorite team, could be info_matches.team_id1 OR info_matches.team_id2 or even both.

Here is a small design for the involved tables :

[image: design]

What I've tried, works 80% (so it doesn't :( ) because it returns some users correct (they fav. teams by 3+ goals diff) , but also returns users which don't have a fav. team in the situation. I think that they are returned because they've made a live checkin for a match where one team or the other has won by a 3+ goals diff.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    f.id 
FROM 
    fanusers f 
LEFT JOIN 
    checkins c ON f.id = c.fanuser_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    info_matches m ON m.id = c.match_id 
WHERE 
    c.ctype = 'live' AND
(
        m.team_id1 IN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    m1.team_id1
                FROM
                    info_matches m1
                RIGHT JOIN 
                                        fanusers_teams ft ON m1.team_id1 = ft.team_id
                RIGHT JOIN 
                                        fanusers f ON f.id = ft.fanuser_id
                WHERE
                    m1.pointsteam1 - m1.pointsteam2 >= 3
                  )
        OR 

        m.team_id2 IN(
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    m2.team_id2
                    FROM
                    info_matches m2
                RIGHT JOIN 
                                        fanusers_teams ft ON m2.team_id2 = ft.team_id
                RIGHT JOIN 
                                        fanusers f ON f.id = ft.fanuser_id
                WHERE
                    m2.pointsteam2 - m2.pointsteam1 >= 3
                  )
)
```

I would appreciate also a small explanation regarding what am I doing wrong, if there is someone who succeed to solve this query.

Thanks.

Comment: Jumping right out at me is that LEFT join you're doing from fanusers to checkins; you definitely don't want that, as you *only* want users who have checked into the game. I'd start there in your analysis and see if any of those other OUTER joins should be INNER.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT f.id 

FROM    fanusers f 

        JOIN checkins c 
        ON f.id = c.fanuser_id 

        JOIN fanusers_teams ft
        ON f.id = ft.fanuser_id

        JOIN info_matches m 
        ON m.id = c.match_id 
        AND 
        (
            (ft.team_id = m.team_id1 AND pointsteam1 - pointsteam2 >= 3) 
        OR 
            (ft.team_id = m.team_id2 AND pointsteam2 - pointsteam1 >= 3)
        )

WHERE   c.ctype = 'live'
```

Comment: Very elegant, and needs no explanations. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  I tried to simplify it as much as possible.  The simplest solution is usually the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found also a way to solve the query, but not so nice as Tom did it.

My way :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                            f.id AS user_id
                        FROM
                            fanusers f
                        LEFT JOIN
                            checkins c ON f.id = c.fanuser_id
                        LEFT JOIN
                            info_matches m ON m.id = c.match_id
                        WHERE
                            c.ctype = 'live' 
                            AND
                            m.matchisfinished = 1 
                            AND
                            c.fanuser_id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                                            f1.id
                                                                        FROM
                                                                            fanusers f1
                                                                        LEFT JOIN
                                                                            fanusers_stickers fs
                                                                        ON f1.id = fs.fanuser_id
                                                                        WHERE
                                                                            fs.sticker_id = 35
                                                                    ) 
                            AND
                            (
                                ( m.team_id1 IN  (  SELECT DISTINCT
                                                                                ft.team_id
                                                                            FROM
                                                                                fanusers_teams ft 
                                                                            INNER JOIN
                                                                                checkins c1
                                                                            ON
                                                                                ft.fanuser_id = c1.fanuser_id
                                                                            WHERE
                                                                                f.id = c1.fanuser_id
                                                                    ) 
                                        AND
                                        m.pointsteam1-m.pointsteam2>=3
                                    )

                                    OR

                                    (
                                         m.team_id2 IN  (   SELECT DISTINCT
                                                                                    ft.team_id
                                                                                FROM
                                                                                    fanusers_teams ft 
                                                                                INNER JOIN
                                                                                    checkins c1
                                                                                ON
                                                                                    ft.fanuser_id = c1.fanuser_id
                                                                                WHERE
                                                                                    f.id = c1.fanuser_id
                                                                        ) 
                                            AND
                                            m.pointsteam2-m.pointsteam1>=3
                                    )
                            )
```

So for the moment, even if I'm happy that I've solved the query by myself, I will use Tom's query :).